# How do I do this change of variables?

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

> Use a change of variables to evaluate:
>   $$\iiint\limits_{D}xy\,\mathrm{d}V$$$D$ is bounded by the planes $y-x=0$, $y-x = 2$, $z-y = 0$, $z-y = 1$, $z=0$, $z=3$.

I set $$u = y-x$$ $$v = z-y$$ $$w = z$$ Isolating for $x$, $y$ and $z$, you get $$x = -u - v+w$$$$y=w-v$$ $$z=w$$

I calculated the Jacobian to be $1$.

The integral would then be:

$$1\dot{}\int_0^3 \int_0^1 \int_0^2 (-u-v+w)(w-v)\,\mathrm{d}u \,\mathrm{d}v\,\mathrm{d}w$$

Which evaluates to $17$, which is incorrect. It's supposed to be $5$. Does anyone know why?

Comment: I think you've set it up correctly but made an error in integration - [WolframAlpha returns 5 for the integral](http://goo.gl/iDhNsT).

Comment: @MarkMcClure Fair enough, thanks. Please post your comment as an answer, I'll accept it as soon as it allows me too.

Comment: Your method is correct. I checked and the integral does evaluate to $5$. You must have made an algebra mistake somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your calculation. Check your anti derivatives. 
[image: integral]